# Is there any compilable into .Net from C#, expandable via C# scripting language?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting

So 3 things are required:

- pure IL/C# generation from script
- abilety to throw in C# classes and grammar constructs
- simple C# api

Generally I want api like this:

```
var sctipt = "Script...";
var scriptConstruct =  "{0} \{ {1} \}";
ScriptCompiler.registerConstruct<Action<string, string> >(scriptConstruct);
ScriptCompiler.reginsterType(ClassT);
ScriptCompiler.bindFunction<Action<String> >(MyFunction, "FunctionNameInScript")
var CompiledScript = ScriptCompiler.Compile(sctipt);
CompiledScript.execute();
```

Is there any such Scripting language?
I tried Nemerle but could not find how to work with it in the way I just described.

Answer (score 1):

A new project called Roslyn is in development at the moment and does exactly what you are looking for. It is available as a Community Technology Preview. Many improvements have been made so i suggest you try it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at this for a good while, but your question brings to mind [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx):

> The Roslyn CTP previews the next generation of language object models
>   for code generation, analysis, and refactoring, and the upcoming
>   support for scripting and interactive use of VB and C#.

There's some stuff kicking around on this, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113169/C-As-A-Scripting-Language-In-Your-NET-Applications).

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the following link ?

http://reverseblade.blogspot.com/2009/02/dont-wait-for-c-5-use-nemerle.html

That way  you can run things dynamically

Comment: my main objective is to provide a scripting enviroment as minor part of existing C# infrastructure. I havent found how to do what I described in code sample with nemerle from C#.